# how to apply if statement for form's <select> relation

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, if-statement, select

in real, i want to make this:
i have 2 select field with some options in my form, and i want: if in first  i select an option (for example with id="2"), second select filed changes auto pay attention to first field selected option.

```
<form>
<select>
   <option id="1"></option>
   <option id="2"></option>
   <option id="3"></option>
</select>
   #in here if select option with 1 id show select field with 1th id:
<select id="1th">
    #options here...
</select>

   #if select option with 2 id show select field with 2th id:
<select id="2th">
    #options here...
</select>

   #if select option with 3 id show select field with 3th id:
<select id="3th">
    #options here...
</select>
</form>
```

(change form other fields by changing form select field).

if you can make this with jquery. it will better even.
thanks.

Comment: This is called connected selects.

Comment: Do not use `id` starting with numbers.

Comment: Please write what have you tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jQuery and the value of the first select element, this is easy to create.

```
<select id="first-select">
   <option value="1"></option>
   <option value="2"></option>
   <option value="3"></option>
</select>
```

Note: Don't use id's like you did, use values instead.
For each subselect, add an id and a class, which we will use to show and hide the right selects.

```
<select id="select-1" class="hideIfNotSelected">
    #options here
</select>
```

Then use this jQuery.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#first-select").on('change', function(event) {
         var selected = this.val();

         $(".hideIfNotSelected").hide(); //hide all selects
         $("#select-"+ selected).show(); //show only the selected select.
    });

});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start with this:

```js
$(function () {
  var sel_1 = ["", "One", "Two", "Three"];
  var sel_2 = [
    [""],
    ["", "One-One", "One-Two", "One-Three"],
    ["", "Two-One", "Two-Two", "Two-Three"],
    ["", "Three-One", "Three-Two", "Three-Three"]
  ];
  // Build it for select 3 yourself.
  $("#sel-1").html(function () {
    var final = "";
    $.each(sel_1, function (i, v) {
      final += "<option value='" + i + "'>" + v + "</option>";
    });
    return final;
  }).change(function () {
    reset(2);
    var final = "";
    $.each(sel_2[$(this).val()], function (i, v) {
      final += "<option value='" + i + "'>" + v + "</option>";
    });
    $("#sel-2").html(final).off("change").change(function () {
      $("#sel-3").html('');
    });
  });
  function reset(sel) {
    if (sel == 2)
      $("#sel-2, #sel-3").html("");
    else if (sel == 3)
      $("#sel-3").html('<option value="item-2">Item 1</option><option value="item-3">Item 2</option><option value="item-4">Item 3</option>');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<select name="sel-1" id="sel-1"></select>
<select name="sel-2" id="sel-2"></select>
<select name="sel-3" id="sel-3"></select>
```